# SQL Count/Sum displaying column as rows

Tags: sql, rows

I have a table with 4 bit columns
I need to create a report that will show the total of all "true" values for each column but I need the column names to return as a row.
For examples, the table will contain:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1          1      0
0          1      0
1          1      0
```

The result should be:

```
Category Value
Column1    2
Column2    3
Column3    0
```

The table has other columns, I just need specific ones

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are other approaches, but the following should work:

```
select 'Column1' as "Category", sum(column1) as "Value" from my_table union
select 'Column2', sum(column2) from my_table union
select 'Column3', sum(column3) from my_table
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0dfd/1) for it.

Comment: Didn't see anything about a particular SQL version in the question or tags. Did I miss something?

Comment: no i just informed you that wouldn't work in sql server..and u miss single qoute after column2

Comment: Looks a bit messy, thought there was an easier way. But it works (Only I had to use sum(Case when...) beacause the columns are bit)

Comment: Just curious, what SQL version are you using?  sum(..) works on bit in MySQL.

Comment: @AmitSingh - Thanks for pointing out the typo. For future reference, can you explain the meaning of the "??" at the end of your first comment about it not working in sql server?

Comment: ahhh sorry i have habit of including ? in my comments sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You can try UNPIVOT on the table (this is for SQL Server)

```
create table Test (Column1 bit, Column2 bit, Column3 bit)

insert into Test values (1,1,0)
insert into Test values (0,1,0)
insert into Test values (1,1,0)

SELECT Value, sum(Vals)
FROM
   (CONVERT(INT, Column1) Column1, CONVERT(INT, Column2) Column2, CONVERT(INT, Column3) Column3
   FROM Test) p
UNPIVOT
   (Vals FOR Value IN
      (Column1, Column2, Column3)
)AS unpvt
GROUP BY Value
```

[PIVOT/UNPIVOT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/957c6/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
category = "column1", value = sum (convert(int,col1)) from MyTable1
union
select 
category = "column2", value = sum (convert(int,col2)) from MyTable1
union
select 
category = "column3", value = sum (convert(int,col3)) from MyTable1
```